# Add Foreign Key Constraint Swift Vapor Fluent with PostgreSQL

Tags: swift, postgresql, foreign-keys, fluent, vapor

When I launch this command line ***vapor run prepare***, I get the correct tables but the foreign key constraints are not added.

I have a Theme class and a Question class :

Theme:
name,
id

Question:
title,
id,
theme_id

This is the prepare Database function in my Question class :

```
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {

        try database.create("questions") { questions in
            questions.id()
            questions.string("title")
            questions.parent(Theme.self, optional: false)
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign key constraints were added in Fluent 2:

```
try database.create(self) { builder in
    builder.foreignKey("user_id", references: "id", on: User.self)
}
```

More info here:
https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/fluent/database/#foreign-keys

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the supported way anymore. How do we do this in Vapor 3.0 and 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Also, one can add a raw SQL statement during the preparation, which can get you out of most situations. For example one could add this additional line to create a unique constraint across multiple columns.

```
questions.raw("UNIQUE (pararent_id, title)")
```

But serves many purposes...